# Code randomly stopped working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<img id="myImg" src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/193/37281782-random-image.png" onmouseover="zoomIn()" onmouseout="zoomOut()"> 


function zoomIn(){
        alert("test");
  var element = document.getElementById("myImg");
  var newWidth = 450;
  var newHeight = 200;
  if((element.width != newWidth) && (element.height != newHeight)){
      var zoomStart = function(){
          element.width += 1.5;
          element.height += 1;
          if((element.height < newHeight) && (element.width < newWidth)){
              setTimeout(zoomStart, 10);
          }    
      }
      zoomStart();
  }
  }



function zoomOut(){
      var element = document.getElementById("myImg");
      alert("begin2 " + element.width +" "+ element.height);
      var originalWidth = 300;
      var originalHeight = 100;
      if((element.width != originalWidth) && (element.height != originalHeight)){
          var zoomStart = function(){
              element.width -= 1.5;
              element.height -= 1;
              if((element.height > originalHeight) && (element.width > originalWidth)){
                  setTimeout(zoomStart, 10);
              }      
          }
          zoomStart();
      }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3dgrzaz/1/

See the above js fiddle for my code.

The image should enlarge when the mouse moves over it, and become smaller again when the mouse moves off of it.

The code was working fine. I moved the css into a separate file and the code stopped working all of a sudden...

Comment: Have you included your css file into html file?

Comment: That's not actually random, that's in direct response to a stimulus.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Id you check the developers console in the fiddle youll see your errors - `zoomIn()` and `zoomOut()` are undefined.

Comment: To clarify - its not working in the fiddle or its not working locally?

Comment: "*I moved the css into a separate file*" - I see no css in your question - are you talking about js?  If yes, make sure that you are not running your js file onload: https://jsfiddle.net/j3dgrzaz/9/

Comment: code doesn't "randomly stop working". computers are, inherently, not random (even random number generators are not really random). There will always be a cause for something changing. Maybe something you did, maybe not. But there will always be a reason. Examine what has changed and look for causes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the javascript functions before loading the page. So shift it to head and it will work fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/j3dgrzaz/7/

```
<head>

<script>
function zoomIn(){
        alert("test");
  var element = document.getElementById("myImg");
  var newWidth = 450;
  var newHeight = 200;
  if((element.width != newWidth) && (element.height != newHeight)){
      var zoomStart = function(){
          element.width += 1.5;
          element.height += 1;
          if((element.height < newHeight) && (element.width < newWidth)){
              setTimeout(zoomStart, 10);
          }    
      }
      zoomStart();
  }
  }

  function zoomOut(){
      var element = document.getElementById("myImg");
      alert("begin2 " + element.width +" "+ element.height);
       var originalWidth = 300;
      var originalHeight = 100;
      if((element.width != originalWidth) && (element.height != originalHeight)){
          var zoomStart = function(){
              element.width -= 1.5;
              element.height -= 1;
              if((element.height > originalHeight) && (element.width > originalWidth)){
                  setTimeout(zoomStart, 10);
              }      
          }
          zoomStart();
      }
  }

</script>


</head>
```

Comment: Or just add `window.zoomIn = zoomIn; window.zoomOut = zoomOut;` at the end of the js instead of moving the code to the html to expose them?

Comment: @Strille the js code is exposed either way. This answer fixes the problem of the function not being found, yet neither fiddle seems to be doing what was intended (i.e. no zoom in nor zoom out is happening).